# How to unselect specific data in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have selected all the used ranges in my worksheet using `UsedRange.Select`
and wanted to unselect only the upper two ranges. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the selection was made manually. If the selection was made programmatically, don't do this. Instead, just don't select the ranges you don't want to select in the first place.

---

There's no way to "unselect" a range. *Something* needs to be selected, so the way to do this is to select the range you want to end up with.

If multiple cells are selected, then the `Selection` object holds a `Range` reference that contains multiple `Areas`; you can iterate the `Areas` and determine whether an area is one of the two areas in the "upper two ranges" you don't want to keep; if they aren't add them to a new `Range` object using `Union`, and `Select` the union'd range once you've iterated all areas - at a relatively high abstraction level, might look like this:

```
Public Sub DeselectUpperAreas()
    Dim initialSelection As Range
    Set initialSelection = Application.Selection

    Dim finalSelection As Range
    Dim currentArea As Range
    For Each currentArea In initialSelection.Areas
        If Not IsUnwantedRange(currentArea) Then
            Set finalSelection = AppendRange(currentArea, finalSelection)
        End If
    Next

    If Not finalSelection Is Nothing Then finalSelection.Select
End Sub

Private Function IsUnwantedRange(ByVal target As Range) As Boolean
    'TODO evaluate whether target is wanted or not;
    'return True if target is unwanted in the final selection
    'IsUnwantedRange = (boolean expression)
End Function

Private Function AppendRange(ByVal target As Range, ByVal merged As Range) As Range
    If merged Is Nothing Then
        Set AppendRange = target
    Else
        Set AppendRange = Union(target, merged)
    End If
End Function
```

How you implement the `IsUnwantedRange` function is unclear from the question, but one way could be to `Intersect` the specified `target` with a cell you know is inside the range you don't want selected, and return `False` if the intersection is `Nothing`.

Another way could be to pass the whole `initialSelection`, along with the `currentArea`, determine which two areas are the "upper two ranges" (by comparing their `Row` property, I'd guess), and return `True` if `target` is one of the two ranges you don't want to include.

Another way could be to populate an array with the `Row` value of each area, use `WorksheetFunction.Small` (once with `k=1`, once with `k=2`) to locate the two row numbers you don't want (they would be the two smaller values), and then return `True` if `target.Row` is one of these two values.

Note that legitimate uses of `Selection` in VBA for Excel, are very rare; depending on what you intend to do with that selection, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513) might help avoiding to deal with `Select` and `Activate` completely.